# Не могу загрузить файл больше 5 MB

Tags: php, yii2, fileupload

Выдает ошибку:

```
move_uploaded_file(../../frontend/web/source/prices/LT.xls): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

php_value upload_max_filesize 999M
php_value post_max_size 999M
```

Comment: замечательно. а переводчик что говорит по поводу `No such file or directory`? Там есть что-то про размер файла?

Comment: `php_value` то срабатывают?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сначала сохранить модель, а потом загрузить файл.

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post) && $model->save()) {
    $model->file = yii\web\UploadFile();
    $filename = $model->file->getBaseName() . '.' $model->file->getExtension();  
    return $model->file->saveAs($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте по выводу phpinfo() параметры 
file_uploads
max_file_uploads
upload_max_filesize